# route doesn't work in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this Action Method:

```
 public virtual ActionResult NewsByCategory(int code)
    {...}
```

and I have Two Routers like this :

```
routes.MapRoute("lang",
   "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
   new[] { "CMS.mvcApp.Controllers" });

routes.MapRoute("langCode", 
  "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{code}", 
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", code = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
  new[] { "CMS.mvcApp.Controllers" });
```

And I have the below Request :

```
locallhost:3354//En/News/NewsByCategory/12345
```

[image]

I am getting This Error :

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'code' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult NewsByCategory(Int32)' in 'CMS.mvcApp.Controllers.NewsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter

Why doesn't it work ?

Comment: `/En/News/NewsByCategory/12345`matches you first route so its assigned the value `12345` to `id` and `code` is `null` hence the error

Comment: Either delete the second route definintion (and change the method to `NewsByCategory(int id)`) or make a specific route for `NewsByCategory`.

Comment: I want match by secound Route. I want set Parameter name `Code`.

Comment: You cant match your second route (because it matches the first one!). Why you specifically need it to be `code` only you know, but you can create a specific route `routes.MapRoute("langCode", "{lang}/News/NewsByCategory/{code}", new { controller = "News", action = "NewsByCategory" })` but you need to move it before your default route

Comment: I don't see actual difference in both routes

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks , got it . :)

Comment: @brykneval yes , they are the same just `code` and `id` aren't same :)

Comment: @PsarTak yes but they are optional but you got the answer, route depends on route and then parameter :-)

Comment: I add this Route `routes.MapRoute("newscategory", "{lang}/News/Category/{newsCategoryId}", new { controller = "News", action = "Category" }, new[] { "CMS.mvcApp.Controllers" });`  , it match first route too. it want param name in action  `newsCategoryId` . If change `newsCategoryId` To `id` it work fine

Answer (score 3):

MVC is using the first route which you declared in your route.config
files. MVC works in such a way that as soon as it finds any matching
routes it won't look for next declared route in your config. So you
should always add most specific route on the top of the list and most
generic route in bottom of the list.

You can also use the constraints for the parameter type.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs

Comment: If quote you've provided is from some other SO question - mark as duplicate instead, in any case provide location you've obtained quote from.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I didn't copy it from anywhere. I just added it by myself.

Comment: Not sure why you formatted it as a quote than... I've removed that formatting.